# to create video from image sequence on android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, javacv

I want to create video from image sequence (on android) by this code:

```
    opencv_core.IplImage image = cvLoadImage("/sdcard/mytest/testimage.jpg");
    FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder("/sdcard/mytest/test.3gp",256,256);
    try {
        recorder.setCodecID( CODEC_ID_H263);
        recorder.setFormat("3gp");
        recorder.setPixelFormat(  PIX_FMT_YUV420P);
        recorder.start();
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
          {
            recorder.record(image);
          }
        recorder.stop();
       }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

But instead of my image I have got green screen. What I have to change in my code?

And how I can add audio to my video?

Comment: This has been fixed in the [latest FFmpegFrameRecorder.java](http://javacv.googlecode.com/git/src/main/java/com/googlecode/javacv/FFmpegFrameRecorder.java).

Comment: hi @preceptron your problem fixed ?? do you got an video from image files ??? if yes advice me

Comment: hi rajesh did u see my mail.

Comment: did you manage to run this code? A link with a miniproject will be usefull for me.

Comment: can some one post a working example for this ?

Comment: Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170523/create-video-from-images/45892912#45892912) for creating video from image sequence