# Android KitKat start screenrecord from App

Tags: android, screen, record, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm trying to start screenrecord from application, and have some problems.
I've read a lot about executing command but nothing seems to help.

Problem is, When I start screenrecord file, It creates with size 3014 bytes

`(content: [...]ftypisom[...]isom3gp4[...])`, and nothing is recorded in the file.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The screenrecord command is intended to be run from an adb shell. Specifically, it needs to be a member of the AID_GRAPHICS group to function. Normal Android apps do not have this privilege.

Some more detailed information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336338/screen-video-record-of-current-activity-android/22984645#22984645).