# App Screen Recording in android ,Like Talking tom app

Tags: android, video, screen, screenshot, video-processing

I want to record my app screen with audio and can access later,I saw this feature in Talking Tom application. I want to know how can I record my app screen. please help me

Comment: did you mean video recording?

Comment: yes.. I want to generate a video of my app screen when user click a record button.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically recording video from within your app will require root access. You'll notice that the apps available to do this in the Play Store prominently list "REQUIRES ROOT" in their app descriptions.

These links may help..
[Screen Video Record of Current Activity Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336338/screen-video-record-of-current-activity-android)

http://thetechjournal.com/electronics/android/how-to-capture-screenshots-and-record-video-on-android-device.xhtml

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/951-how-to-capture-video-of-the-screen-on-android/

http://www.mightypocket.com/2010/09/installing-android-screenshots-screen-capture-screen-cast-for-windows/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ashot/