# Video Recording with Mobile Vision face detection

Tags: android, face-detection, video-recording

I am building a app where i am using mobile vision sdk for face detection and showing some overlay on face. but i am facing problem while record video. Is there any solution to record video with same problem.

Thanks

Comment: Have you got any solution? i am also facing the same problem of "Video recording with face detection parllel on same view"

Comment: What problem do you face?

Answer (score 0):

Since Android 5.0 there is a new API that can be used for screen recording: MediaProjection. The MediaProjection grants the ability to capture screen content, but not system audio. Also it won't capture secure screen content. You need user permission for capturing the screen. Please refer to this for screen recording. 
[Screen Video Record of Current Activity Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336338/screen-video-record-of-current-activity-android)