# Is it possible to share screen one device to another device in android?

Tags: android

Is it possible to share screen one device to another device in android ???

While video call or audio call is running in android want to share my device's screen to other device so is it possible in android pragmatically?? please help

Comment: Something like [this](https://github.com/Temasys/skylink-android-screen-sharing)?

Comment: yes but while audio or video call is running .. @Piyush

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it possible via Android's [MediaProjection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection.html) api.

As per **documentation** :

> A screen capture session can be started through
>   `MediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent()`. This grants the
>   ability to capture screen contents, but not system audio.

**Please note:**  You can use this api only on device with API Level 21+ or android 5.0+

You can refer [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336338/screen-video-record-of-current-activity-android/31005187#31005187) for implementation !

Comment: sure, don't forget to hit the tick icon, If my answer helped you :)