# Creating a video in android

Tags: java, android, video

What is the ideal way to create a video in android platform using JAVA?

I tried using ffmpeg but really got in trouble compiling it. I know there's a class that supports all these things in the iOS, it's called : AVFoundation. Does android has a similiar API for the encoding/decoding, buffers?

my goal is to create a video in Android and It seems to be too difficult to do such things on Android..... Are there any other solution for these things that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `libav` framework.You can refer this link.

[Create video from images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170523/create-video-from-images)

But this has been developed in C.So you have to access it via JNI

Comment: I don't know how to build that framework on my android application, all tutorials I see about it is using Linux based OS, could you give me please some instructions on compiling it please?

Comment: @idish, There is android OS that can be installed in Virtual Machine.http://www.android-x86.org/ and dumb this code there and you can compile it.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much, can I add you via skype/MSN or any other chat, so if I'll get in trouble you could help me please?

Comment: @idish, no problem....:).Do you have any gmail account? this is my google chat iD. unnivm@gmail.com

Comment: Very well, I added you :) I'll talk to you when I'm getting in trouble, thank you!