# create video from series of images android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, android-mediacodec, jcodec

I am trying to create a video from series of images in android.
I have come across these three options MediaCodec, ffmpeg using ndk and jcodec. Can someone let me know which one of them is best and easiest. I didn't find any proper documentation so can somebody please post their working example?

Comment: Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170523/create-video-from-images/45892912#45892912)

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about API 4.3+ in general you need to get input surface from encoder, copy image to the texture that comes along with the surface, put correct timestamp and send it back to encoder. and do it

```
fps (frames per second) * resulted video duration in seconds
```

times. encoder bitstream after encoder should go to the muxer, so finally you will get mp4 file. 
It requires rather much coding:)

I suggest you to try free Intel Media Pack: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials

It has a sample - JpegSubstituteEffect, it allows to create videos from images. The idea is to take a dummy video (black video and quiet audio) and to substitute all black frame by coping images. It could be easily enhanced to creating a video from series of images. I know a couple of applications in Google Play making the same using Media Pack

Answer (score 3):

I tried JCodec 1.7 for Android. This is very simple compared to the other two options and works. There is class SequenceEncoder in the android package that accepts Bitmap instances and encodes them in to video. I ended up cloning this class into my app to override some of the settings e.g. fps. Problem with JCodec is that performance is dismal - encoding single 720x480 pixels frame takes just about 45 seconds. I wanted to do timelapse videos possibly at fullHD and  was initially thinking any encoder will do as I was not expecting encoding a frame to take more than a second (minimal interval between frames in my app is 3 seconds). As you can guess with 45 seconds per frame JCodec is not a fit.

I am monitoring your question for other answers that may be helpful.

The MediaCodec/MediaMuxer way seems ok but it is insanely complex. I need to learn quite a bit about OpenGL ES, video formats and some Android voodoo to get this going. Ohh and this only works on the latest crop of phones 4.3+. This is real shame for Google with all of their claims to fame. I found some Stackoverflow discussions on the topic.  Two sub-paths exist - the OpenGL way is device independent. There is another way which involves transcoding your RGB Bitmap data to YUV. the catch with YUV is that there are 3 flavours of it depending on the device HW - planar, semi planar and semi planar compressed (I am not sure if a 4th way is not coming in the future so...).

Here are couple useful links on the OpenGL way

CTS test - https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java

Many CTS like tests - http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#EncodeDecodeTest

Two of them seem to be relevant and useful

EncodeAndMuxTest - http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/EncodeAndMuxTest.java.txt
CameraToMpegTest - http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/CameraToMpegTest.java.txt (I believe this to be closest to what I need, just need to understand all the OpenGL voodoo and get my Bitmap in as texture filling up the entire frame i.e. projections, cameras and what not comes into play)

ffmpeg route does not seem direct enough too. Something in C++ accepting stuff from Java...I guess some weird conversions of the Bitmap to byte[]/ByteBuffer will be first needed - cpu intensive and slow. I actually have JPEG byte[] but am not sure this will come handy to the ffmpeg library. I am not sure if ffmpeg is taking leverage of the GPU or other HW acceleration so it may well end up at 10 seconds per frame and literally baking the phone.

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg can implement this task. You first need compile ffmpeg library in Android (refer to this article "[How to use Vitamio with your own FFmpeg build](https://www.vitamio.org/en/2013/Tutorial_0509/13.html)")

You could refer the samples in FFmpeg to figure out how to implement your task.

In Android implement your task in C++; then use JNI to integrate the C++ code into your Android app.